# How can we use multiple Ids/content in a single selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Please suggest me proper jquery selector for this.
how  to optimise this?Please suggest

```
$("#name").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});
$("#userName").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the code with following.

```
$("#name,#userName").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#Search").click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this :-

```
 $("#name,#userName").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#Search").click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

call with same class name for both , then refer that class

```
$(".name").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1**

You want to reference items by ID but apply the same logic, use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#name,#userName").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});
```

**Option 2**

You want to apply the same logic to a group of items, but not by ID. In that case, use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(".MyGroup").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});

// Apply .MyGroup class to each item you wish to capture the keyup event
// <input type="text" class="MyGroup" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("#name, #userName").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Search").click();
    }
});
```